# [oracle@linuxuser ~]$ dbca -bash: dbca: command not found

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

i'm installing 11G on Enterprise version linux. after executing ./runInstaller and setting bashprofile when i'm firing dbca on tightVNC am facing this problem of not finding command dbca.
please help me!! what to do next?

Comment: Hey!it works. I had mistake in my bashprofile. Yeah.great thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your PATH correctly, or run `dbca` by specifying the absolute path. For example:

```
$ export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
$ export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
$ dbca
```

Or run dbca with absolute path:

```
$ /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbca
```